# Dynamic creation of methods/objects with jinja/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I've got this working code right now,
For example' sake I made a straight forward piece of code:

```
{% for t in things %}
<button id="name{{t.id}}">{{ t.text }}</button>
<script>
$('#name{{ t.id }}').on('click', function() {
console.log('testingscript');
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

But since this is not a good way to mix html/js I'd like to either put the js in a seperate file or a jinja solution..

EDIT: The q is how do i do this?

Comment: Cool man. What's your question?

Comment: @David How would i put the script part in a seperate file OR the whole for loop. ( I think the js file is the easy way)

Comment: Are all the clicks going to perform the same task? For example: `console.log('testingscript');` ?

Comment: If the callback is always the same you could associate a class with the buttons. Then you'd only need one `onclick`.

Comment: @BidhanA Yes, I will add {{ t.text }} to make them usefull. It was rather for setting an example. The point is they all need a different onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a lot of script tags. Instead, try something like this in the head:

```
<script>
    $('button.mybutton').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

and the body has

```
{% for t in things %}
    <button class="mybutton" id="name{{t.id}}">{{ t.text }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Therefore, whenever a button with class `mybutton` is clicked, the *single* script writes its contained text to the console. The `id` isn't what is invoking the callback, the `class` is.

Comment: In some cases, this might be a good answer. But in my case, sorry if i didn't make myself clear, I want all the buttons to do something different. e.g. print the {{ t.text }}